A technical lemma in the lecture notes of Yoccoz on interval exchange maps
I'm reading the elegantly written lecture notes "Continued Fraction Algorithms for Interval Exchange Maps" of Yoccoz, available through the link <www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-christophe-yoccoz/UPL13956_yoccoz.pdf>.
Somehow I'm confused by the proof of Lemma 4 in Section 4.4, pages 17-18. The lemma states that the probability that an interval exchange map $T$ with given first $n$ steps in the Rauzy diagram has a big $Q^{'}_{\alpha}(T)$ is small. Here $Q^{'}_{\alpha}(T)$ is the $l^1$ length of the column vector related to the first appearing time of symbol $\alpha$ as a "name", crucial in analyzing the simplicial dynamics on the parameter space.
The proof goes by induction on the first appearing time $\bar{n}$ of $\alpha$ as a "name". The strategy is to show a stronger version of the statement, conditioning on the value of $\bar{n}$. However, I don't quite follow the inductive step. Especially the last paragraph seems to be a puzzling mixture of the conditional version and the original version of the statement. Could someone please shed some light on this? Is there some exposition of this result with more details?

It seems that Prop. 1.3 in "simplicial systems for interval exchange maps and measured foliations" by Kerckhoff corresponds to Lemma 4 mentioned above, with a different proof. However, the inductive proof in Yoccoz's notes is still confusing to me.
